# Make rest api formatted correctly with nodejs and Lamda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to format a json rest api so that it isn't minified. I am using NodeJs/lambda and AWS API gateway. What I want is:

**From this:**

```
{"name":"Ultimate data","description":"This is an example api build for get requests","number":"40"}
```

**To this:**

```
{
   "name":"Ultimate data",
   "description":"This is an example api build for get requests",
   "number":"40"
}
```

**my nodejs code**

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
   if (event.httpMethod === 'GET') {
       return getData(event);
   }
};

const getData = event => {
    let data = {
           name: 'Ultimate data',
           description: 'This is an example api build for get requests',
           number: '40'
    };
       return {
           statusCode: 200,
           body: JSON.stringify(data)
       };
};
```

Is it an option somewhere in APi Gateway/Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)` should do. 2 is basically the indentation spaces.

Comment: @Sole - cool.. feel free to mark it as answer for other people's reference.

Comment: yes I will once the time frame has passed where I can accept